# rsyslog: facilities not separating

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, rsyslog

I will preface this with, I am a Linux newbie. I had set up a Debian Linux rsyslog server that was working, but I had to switch to Ubuntu. I was hoping that I would be able to just copy the parts of the config over and it would work. That has not been the case.

My syslog is receiving the information, however it is just wrinting to the default file `/var/log/syslog`.

Here is my current config, I have edited out the items that were commented out:

```
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support

$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

$RepeatedMsgReduction on

$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

#this was a template given to me that had worked in debian - Thanks Aaron Copley
$template Firewall,"/var/log/prd/fwlog-%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%"
$template Switch,"/var/log/prd/rslog-%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%"

Local7.* -?Firewall
Local4.* -?Switch
```

Is there some things that differ for rsyslog in Ubuntu vs. Debian?

Comment: You should try some [rsyslog debugging](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/debug.html) first, hopefully that will show how your messages are being processed.

Comment: @PhilHollenback - I think getting the rsyslog debugging is a great idea, I am just baffled as to why this worked in one OS and not another version of it.

Comment: We need to know what version of rsyslog you are running so we can be sure this syntax is correct for this version. Rsyslogd has changed so much, I can't keep it all straight. The other possibility is your daemon is being started in some compatibility mode that cripples/disables templates. Check to see the command line options it was started with and post here. (`ps aux | grep rsyslog`)

Comment: @AaronCopley - `swVersion="7.4.4"` The output was--`sudo ps aux | grep rsyslog root 10852 0.0 0.1 67044 2148 ? S 12:32 0:00 sudo rsyslogd -n syslog 10853 3.0 0.1 370836 2544 ? Sl 12:32 11:27 rsyslogd -n network+ 12093 0.0 0.0 11744 916 pts/18 S+ 18:52 0:00 grep --color=auto rsyslog`

Comment: @AaronCopley - I see now that the version on Debian Wheezy is different from Ubuntu14.04.1 LTS, ack....I must have looked at the dropdown on rsyslog.com 50 times...and didn't think to check the version. So I will need to at the very least, redo my template. I would love help with that, if possible.